# Using jQuery UI Tabs, can't get Tabs position to be absolute

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I'm trying to make the tabs in a tabs widget fixed to an absolute position.
See http://jsfiddle.net/5umRd/3/

```
<div id="houseBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Hnew">New Households</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Hactive">Active Routes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Hinactive">Inactive Routes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Hgone">Moved Out</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="Hnew" style="overflow-y: auto">
        Loading new households...
    </div>
    <div id="Hactive" style="overflow-y: auto">
        will contain table of currently used houses
    </div>
    <div id="Hinactive" style="overflow-y: scroll">
        will contain table of hidden houses
    </div>
    <div id="Hgone">
        will contain list of previously known houses that have disappeared from the list
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css styles:

```
    #houseBar { top: 0; position: absolute; max-height: 300px; max-width: 98%; overflow-y: scroll }
    #Hnew, #Hactive, #Hinactive, #Hgone {height: 3000px}
```

Basically, I want to be able to see the tabs at all times no matter where I'm scrolling in each content div (having the content dive scrollable would be a plus too).

After playing around for a few hours with different css styles, I just decided I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your style

```
#houseBar { top: 0; position: absolute; height: 300px; width: 70%; overflow-y: scroll }
```

instead of using max-width , just use width , this will give u a fixed width.

Comment: Wasn't asking about width? I need to have the Tabs visible at all times, width is not a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/5umRd/26/)**

**CSS:**

```
/* Generic pane rules */
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.scroll-x {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.scroll-y {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#houseBar ul {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 98%;
}
#houseBar ul li {
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:40px;
}
#houseBar>div, #Hnew, #Hactive, #Hinactive, #Hgone {
    position relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 3000px;
    padding-top:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey
}
```

Comment: Looks great! But I made a goof on my part not including the map-canvas div. Somehow also, this css rule separates the content tabs from the tab container? jsfiddle.net/5umRd/28/  the map-canvas should basically be the background. Looks very close though!